# Sorted dict items without lambda

Tags: python, arrays, list, numba

I am looking for a straightforward, alternative way to writing this, without lambda:

```
sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda i: -i[1])
```

I have tried using the operator module but without success, in terms of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import operator

# ...
sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```